# How to globally handle HTTP errors in Grails (status codes 4xx/5xx)?

Tags: grails, error-handling, http-status-codes

Is there a way in Grails to catch all the possible HTTP errors before they're being sent to the client browser, as to be able to handle the content being sent to the client? I mean **all 4xx and 5xx HTTP status codes**, not only the 403, 404 and 500 like other have suggested.

What I'd like to do is to catch all HTTP errors in the first place, without having to specify them all one by one, then in a second step I would filter (e.g. in an error controller) specific error codes that I would like to handle (e.g. 400), but at least the ones that I would not specify would render to a generic error template I defined.

If this can't be done (or shouldn't be done), which HTTP errors codes should really be checked for and handled? I can at least see those codes happening at some point: 400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 500, 501, 503. And also, how should they be handled, using HTTP response codes mappings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

haven't actually tried it but maybe a number constraint might work?

```
"$errorCode" {
     controller = "errors"
     action = "displayError"
     constraints {
          errorCode(matches:/\d{3}/)
     }
}
```

Comment: Hey Aaron, just tried your suggestion, but it turns out that Grails is failing when trying to run the application. The following is being written to the log:
2010-12-06 11:10:23,984 [main] ERROR context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib': Initialization of bean failed