# Generic URLMapping in Grails for all 4xx or 5xx Errors

Tags: grails, http-response-codes, urlmappings.groovy

I am using Grails 2.4.4 and would like to define a generic UrlMapping for a range of HTTP-error-codes (like 450-499, 510-540).

I've found some related questions - even on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367594/how-to-globally-handle-http-errors-in-grails-status-codes-4xx-5xx) - but the answers are either outdated or not working.

The container does not start once I use regular expressions on error-mappings.

For instance, this simple example will fail:

```
"$errorCode" {
     controller = "error"
     action = "general"
     constraints {
          errorCode(matches:/\d{3}/)
     }
}
```

Does anyone know how I may approach this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing same using Filters but we cannot redirect again after checking status code in httpResponse hence that also doesn't help.

As per grails-doc "Mapping to Response Codes"

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.x/guide/single.html#urlmappings

we can only hard code them and redirect it to mentioned controller and action.
So you need to mention all http codes and handle all of them separately.

Thanks.